# Django-like data model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, django, django-models

Is there anything similar to Django data models in ASP.NET MVC where I can easily manipulate my classes and objects and don't worry about SQL realization of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django uses it's own ORM Implementation, just like ROR uses Active Records. ASP.NET MVC on the other hand doesn't include any type of ORM Implementation. You need to find a good .NET ORM I suggest checking out http://ormbattle.net/

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of [FluentNHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/)'s [AutoMapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) and [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).  It's pretty close to a Django/Web2Py type setup, minus the auto creation of admin screens.

My Domain models then are completely clean, and if I do have to do mapping manipulation, and it's rare I do, it then resides in AutoMapping overrides that don't clutter up my domain implementation.

Fluent + nHibernate is pretty slick :)

Also, Microsoft's upcoming [Entity Framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) looks promising, but it's still pretty early in development.